# Create an infinite horizontal line

Tags: css, html, css-position

I'd like to create an infinite horizontal div. However, I have no idea about how to do it.

Can someone help me to do it using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/PstWc/) as a start point?

Please, take a look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT2Ab.png) to understand how this infinite horizontal div should be.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more detail - does the horizontal line need to start over on the right (i.e. #line in the image) and head off to infinity to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "infinite" i am assuming you mean to the end of the wiewport/window. You could try an absolutely  positioned element;

this will be an overlay, appearing on top of anything in normal document flow

**html**

```
<div id="line">&nbsp;</div>
```

**css**

```
#line {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    left: 50%; /* seeing as content is centered, make margin-left start at center of page */
    bottom: 10%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/PstWc/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a 1px high div set to 100% width:

```
 <div class="inf_line">
    &nbsp;
 </div>


.inf_line {width: 100%; height: 1px; background-color: #333; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/PstWc/1/).

Might not be the most elegant way to do it, but it's a way.